# Having a method update/reload its self everytime it gets called? Ruby

Tags: ruby, math

My long term goal is replicate [this spreadsheet](http://www.vertex42.com/Calculators/debt-reduction-calculator.html) in a ruby program and then to a rails app.

Currently I am trying to make it determine which of the two debts has the highest interest then subtract the minimum amount from that debt as well as any extra amounts the person is willing to pay as well as subtracting the minimum value from the other debt.

example:

```
card = balance: $10,000, Minimum: $200, i% = 20%
loan = balance: $40,000, Minimum: $400, i% = 5%
payments made per month = $1000
```

In this case, the program would every month firstly take $600 ($1000 -($200 + $400) + $200) from the card until it's balance was 0 then take $1000 ($1000 - $400 + $400) until the loan was payed off and return how many months that would take.

Currently, I am trying to get the amount to subtract each month take into account the balance of the debt and have this update whenever the method is called - however this does not seem to be working and will stay at $400 for both debts (snowball_amount method). **EDIT**: missing method issue fixed. Needed to change attr_reader to attr_accessor*Also for some reason, when I pass a debt object into highest_interest, i'm getting an undefined method 'balance=' error. Would be grateful for some help with this!*

Create a Debt Class

```
class Debt
  def initialize(balance: b, monthly_payment: m, annual_interest_rate: a)
    @balance = balance
    @monthly_min = monthly_payment
    @int_rate = annual_interest_rate
  end
  attr_reader :monthly_min, :balance, :int_rate
end
```

Create two debt objects

```
@debt1 = Debt.new(balance: 14000.0, monthly_payment: 200.0, annual_interest_rate: 0.06)
@debt2 = Debt.new(balance: 40000.0, monthly_payment: 400.0, annual_interest_rate: 0.08)
```

Put them into array

```
@debts_array = [@debt1, @debt2]
```

Set the amount the person is willing to pay each month

```
@payment = 1000.0
```

Determine how much extra is being payed i.e. @payment - each debts monthly minimum, only if that debt's balance is over 0

```
def snowball_amount
  @payments_less_mins = @payment
  @debts_array.each do |debt|
    if debt.balance <= 0
      @payments_less_mins
    elsif debt.balance > 0
      @payments_less_mins = @payments_less_mins - debt.monthly_min
    end
  end
  puts @payments_less_mins
  return @payments_less_mins
end
```

Method for calculating the balance of that debt for that month

```
def compounding_interest(balance, apr)
  return balance * (1 + apr/12)**1
end
```

Determing how long it will take to pay the debt off. While the balance of the debt is above 0 firstly update the balance in line with the addition of interest, then subtract from the debt balance the minimum monthly payment and the snowball(extra amount) from the balance. Then set the debts balance to 0

```
def highest_interest(debt, snowball)
  months_to_pay = 0
  while debt.balance > 0
    debt.balance = compounding_interest(debt.balance, debt.int_rate)
    debt.balance = debt.balance - (debt.monthly_min + snowball)
    months_to_pay += 1
  end
  debt.balance = 0
  snowball_amount
  puts months_to_pay
end
```

Determine which debt has the highest balance and then do the highest interest method on that debt.

```
def which_has_higher_interest
  debts_array = @debts_array.sort{|i| i.int_rate}.reverse!
  puts debts_array[0].balance
  debts_array.each do |debt|
    highest_interest(debt, snowball_amount)
  end
end
```

Calling the which_has_higher_interest method

```
puts which_has_higher_interest
```

Comment: Question is too long. Most people will not feel like reading it. Please make it more concise.

Answer (score 1):

In lines 3, 4, and 7 of your `highest_interest` method, you are calling a method called `balance=` on a `Debt` object, but your `Debt` objects do not have such a method. You need to define it somehow, possibly by changing the line

```
attr_reader :monthly_min, :balance, :int_rate
```

to

```
attr_reader :monthly_min, :int_rate
attr_accessor :balance
```